# Remove column awk

Tags: awk, split, gsub, substr

I have input file:

```
HEADER 1     |  HEADER 2   |  HEADER 3      |  HEADER 3   | HEADER 4       |
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693|
```

**I want my file to be like:** (contain 3 splitted files with header and trailer plus remove first 3 columns

```
DETAIL 07032017
 HEADER 1    |  HEADER 2      |       
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
EOF 3

DETAIL 07032017
 HEADER 1    |  HEADER 2      |
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
EOF 3

DETAIL 07032017
 HEADER 1    |  HEADER 2      |
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
EOF 3
```

As for my current command;

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
{file="FILE_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv";  
print (a[file]++?"": "DM9 "date"" ORS h ORS) $0> file} END{for(file in a)     
print "EOF " a[file] > file}' testing.csv
```

I only can get (as command above) I can split files, add header and trailer but **not yet remove the column**:

```
DETAIL 07032017
 HEADER 1    |  HEADER 2   |  HEADER 3      |  HEADER 3   | HEADER 4       |
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693| 
EOF 3

DETAIL 07032017
 HEADER 1    |  HEADER 2   |  HEADER 3      |  HEADER 3   | HEADER 4       |
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693| 
EOF 3

DETAIL 07032017
 HEADER 1    |  HEADER 2   |  HEADER 3      |  HEADER 3   | HEADER 4       |
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693|
EOF 3
```

the command above only for splitting, add header and trailer with record count.

But I want to remove the first 3 columns after splitting and add header trailer. Is it possible?

Or I need to split then remove and only the last one doing header and trailer?

I try this;

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
{file="FILE_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv";  
print (a[file]++?"": "DM9 "date"" ORS h ORS)**substr($0, index($0,$4))**>             file} END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}' testing.csv
```

I used substr but doesnt work at all.

**I WANT TO REMOVE FIRST 3 COLUMNS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote on previous post, you can remove the columns 1 to 3 using `substr($0, index($0,$4))`. 
Your sample file above is missing header, so I added a header to make the test.

Test results below should give you what you expect.

If in your machine this does not work, probably something is different in your PC.

```
echo "cat data.csv"
cat data.csv
echo "awk - started "
awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"|" 'NR==1 {h=substr($0, index($0,$4)); next} \
{file="FILE_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv";print (a[file]++?"": "DM9 "date"" ORS h ORS) substr($0, index($0,$4)) >file } \
END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] >file}' data.csv
echo "awk - finished "
echo "csv file generated:"
cat FILE*.csv
echo "script finish"

#Terminal Output:
cat data.csv
Header1|Header2|Header3|Header4|Header5|
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693| 
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697|1356438284972|1356438292151693|
awk - started
awk - finished
csv file generated:
DM9 07032017
Header4|Header5|
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
EOF 3
script finish
```

Comment: @Jiji As you can see works fine in Red Hat Linux. Try it online to see your self. What is your system - what is your awk version? Is it MAC , is it BSD, Is it Debian? What is the output of `uname -a` and `awk --version` in terminal? PS: I had to remove also three first columns from header to make output file look nice.

Comment: @Jiji Proposed solutions to drop first three columns work fine in other machines like Red Hat with GNU awk (see online test in my answer - follow the link i provided and watch your first three columns to dissapear). You need to advise what machine are you using and what awk version are you using.

Comment: I use putty or linux machine

Comment: You edited your question to remove first three columns. As this answer does and as the link i gave you does. Follow the link and see how your columns are removed. If you want to post comments for me post them here, not in other posts. About awk version just tell us what your terminal says when you write `awk --version`

Comment: Hi @GeorgeVasiliou i have prob on before coding that u gave me before. If i want to drop first three columns. If my 2nd column name is Project_Today and 3rd column Today. It will cut my 2nd column. Which project_ and today rmain the same. Is it bcause of string problm?

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
    awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'BEGIN{print "DETAIL " date} {print $4,$5FS} END {print "EOF " NR}' OFS="|"  f
DETAIL 07032017
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
EOF 3
```

Comment: {print $4,$5FS} what is this for? I get from column 4 but not fully. Btw I want to do split,header,trailer and remove column in one command. Is it possible? your command only for header,trailer and remove column..splitting is not included in your command

Comment: above my question

Comment: try this - 

`awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next}
{file="FILE_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv";
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"\n") substr($0, index($0,$4)) > file} END{for(file in a)
print "EOF " a[file] > file}' f`

Comment: @Jiji - I don't know what is account number and policy number here, please mention the column number of input file and if you want this to be formatted in your output then change your output file accordingly.

Comment: my column name is missing when i use above command and the first 3 columns still remains...:'( @VIPINKUMAR

Comment: @Jiji - try this command - 

`awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$4FS$5FS; next}
{file="FILE_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv"; print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS ) substr($0, index($0,$4)) > file}
END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file]+1 > file}' f`

It produce result like this -

`DETAIL 07032017
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
1356438284972|1356438292151693|
EOF 3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137430/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-and-jiji).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v Date="$(date +'%d%m%Y')" '
   # print header
   BEGIN { print "DETAIL " Date }
   # prepare new content
      { sub( /([^|][|]){3}/, "") }
   # print new content
   7
   # print footer
   END { print "\nEOF " NR }
   # redirect output to your final file
   ' YourSource > YourFile
```

Comment: I get an error form this one: `awk: cmd. line:5: error: Unmatched ( or \(: /([^|][|]\){3}/`.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu then where is for #split '?

Comment: @Jiji Why does there need to be `split`? You can remove fields without using it, with for example regexps or by printing the fields you want (`print $4,$5,$6`)?

Comment: @JamesBrown Because in reality he has about 15 columns as he had claimed in other posts, not just 6 columns as he is demonstrating in this OP. I am trying to help this guy from yesterday , but no luck. (PS: Have a look in his posting history)

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou  ya actually my command is for split, add header and trailer and the last one i need to drop first three columns. I manage to do split, header and trailer in my command but I could not find way to drop the column. My supervisor give recommend to me to do split first and drop in one command and later do header and trailer. Is it possible? Kindly need you guys respond as im still new using awk. Thank you :) you guys help is appreciated :)

Comment: @JamesBrown ya actually my command is for split, add header and trailer and the last one i need to drop first three columns. I manage to do split, header and trailer in my command but I could not find way to drop the column. My supervisor give recommend to me to do split first and drop in one command and later do header and trailer. Is it possible? Kindly need you guys respond as im still new using awk. Thank you :) you guys help is appreciated :)